# Codeigniter default controller works on Main index page, but not pages within Main controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I configure the route for every page in the `Main` controller?

The Codeigniter default controller only works on `Main` index page, but not on `events`, a page within `Main` controller. *(see below)*

I want `http://example.com/main/events` to be `http://example.com/events` instead.

---

This link takes you to the `Main` controller's index page, like it should:

```
http://example.com/
```

This events page from the `Main` controller takes you to the 404 error page:

```
http://example.com/events
```

The `events` page only works with the default controller in the URL like this:

```
http://example.com/main/events
```

Contents of my routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
$route['404_override'] = 'main/error404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Contents of .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will take you into `events` page when your URL will be `http://example.com/events`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
$route['events'] = 'main/events';
$route['404_override'] = 'main/error404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['events'] = 'main/events';  # www.example.com/events
$route['newPath'] = 'controller/exactPath'; # www.example.com/newPath
```

---

In `.htaccess`(outside application folder)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this should be answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how the router works in codeigniter. You can either:

1. Move the logic in your `function events() {...}` function to it's own `class Events extends`CI_Controller { }` controller's index function
2. Set up custom routes in your [`config/routes.php`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) config file to the methods in your `Main` controller like this: (you can use `(:any)` and other parameters as well):

   ```
   $route['events/(.*)'] = 'main/events/$1';
   ```